# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound weird behavior

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, audio

I'm having this unstable behavior with  `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` .

For some reason, over my (real devices) iPhone 5/6 everything works perfectly.**But sometimes over my (real device) iPhone 6+S, i'm hearing -Sometimes- only 3 or 2 sounds out of 5 that i'm playing**

The function i used to create this sound :

```
  if let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundName, withExtension: "mp3") {
            var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0
            AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &mySound)

            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);

        }
```

Comment: what's your iOS version on these devices? are they different?

Comment: Hey @Allen. Yes. iPhone 5  with 9.1 and the 6 is 8.4 . the iPhone 6+ S is 9.1 as well

Comment: is the cut off in the beginning of the sound or at the end?

Comment: @Allen dosent play at all or play fully(each sound)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do some debug in the code and find out the real cause of the problem, the following code will print out the OSStatus:

```
let result = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &mySound)
print(result)
```

you need to figure out what's wrong when the result is not 0, the most common issue is that the sound file should less than 30 sec., otherwise it will not be able play by system sound service.

another issue is you should create system sound in the start of your app, then play that returned mySound when needed, do not call AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID every time when you play it.

```
import UIKit
import AudioToolbox

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var mySound: SystemSoundID = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let soundName = "mytest"

        if let soundURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource(soundName, withExtension: "mp3") {
            let result = AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundURL, &mySound)
            print(mySound)
            print(result)
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func play (sender: UIButton) {
            AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(mySound);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Allen, Thanks. Can you please add an example(working code) of the second issue? I haven't fully understand. The code i posted above recreate all the variables each sound, as far as I understand they are local, so it doesn't suppose to be a problem + they are about 1-2 sec max.

Comment: see the edited answer, your code could be problematic when you play many times since you are creating new AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID every time you play it.

Comment: oh. Cool. i'll add this to the next update. Thank you!!